# Given a specific function $f$, how to compute the left-inverse of $f$ in the sense of $\approx$?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-equations, harmonic-analysis

For a non-negative function $\varphi$ defined on $[0,\infty)$, the left-inverse $\varphi^{-1}$ of $\varphi$ is defined by setting, $\forall t\geq 0$,
$$\varphi^{-1}(t):=\inf\{u\geq0:\varphi(u)\geq t\}.$$
For two functions $\varphi$ and $\psi$, we say that $\varphi\approx\psi$, if there exist constants $c_1,c_2>0$, such that $\forall t\geq0$,
$$c_1\varphi(t)\leq\psi(t)\leq c_2\varphi(t).$$
Let $p\geq1$, define $f(t):=t^p\ln(e+t)$, $t\geq0$ (this is an example appearing in the paper about equations). How to compute the $f^{-1}$ in the sense of $\approx$? I guess its
answer is $\forall t\geq0$, $$f^{-1}(t)\approx\left[\frac{t}{\ln(e+t)}\right]^{1/p}\quad \text{or}\quad f^{-1}(t)\approx \min\left\{t^{1/p},\left[\frac{t}{\ln(e+t)}\right]^{1/p}\right\},$$ but I do not know how to compute $f^{-1}$ in the sense of $\approx$, I need some help.

Comment: What are the specific titles of "the paper about equations" and "papers about differential equations"?

Comment: Such as *Regularity results for a new class of functionals with
non-standard growth conditions* published in the Journal of Differential Equations.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(t):=t^p\ln(e+t)$ for some real $p>0$ and all real $t\ge0$, then
\begin{equation*}
    f^{-1}(u)\approx g(u):=\frac{u^{1/p}}{\ln^{1/p}(e+u^{1/p})} \label{1}\tag{1}
\end{equation*}
for real $u\ge0$, where the symbol $\approx$ is used in the sense defined in your post.

Indeed, the function $f\colon[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ is continuous and strictly increasing, from $f(0)=0$ to $f(\infty-):=\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)=\infty$. So, $f^{-1}$ is the true inverse of $f$. That is, for all nonnegative real $t$ and $u$ we have
\begin{equation*}
    f(t)=u\iff f^{-1}(u)=t. \label{2}\tag{2}
\end{equation*}

Next,
\begin{equation*}
    Kh(u)\le g(u)\le u^{1/p}, \label{3}\tag{3}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
h(u):=\min(u^{1/p},u^{1/(2p)})=u^{1/p}\,1(u\le1)+u^{1/(2p)}\,1(u>1) \label{4}\tag{4}
\end{equation*}
and $K\in(0,\infty)$ depends only on $p$ (but not on $u$); here and in what follows, $u$ is an arbitrary nonnegative real number, unless further specified. (The first inequality in \eqref{4} holds because $g(0)=h(0)=0$, the functions $g$ and $h$ are continuous and strictly positive on $(0,\infty)$, and for $r(u):=g(u)/h(u)$ $(u>0)$ we have $r(0+)=1>0$ and $r(\infty-)=\infty>0$.)

By the second inequality in \eqref{3},
\begin{equation*}
f(g(u))=u\,\frac{\ln(e+g(u))}{\ln(e+u^{1/p})}\le u=f(f^{-1}(u)). 
\end{equation*}
Therefore and because $f$ is strictly increasing, we have
\begin{equation*}
g(u)\le f^{-1}(u).\label{5} \tag{5}
\end{equation*}

On the other hand, by the first inequality in \eqref{3}, for real $C\ge1$
\begin{equation*}
    f(Cg(u))=C^pu\,\frac{\ln(e+Cg(u))}{\ln(e+u^{1/p})} \label{6}\tag{6}
    \ge C^pu R(u),
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
R(u):=\frac{\ln(e+Kh(u))}{\ln(e+u^{1/p})}. 
\end{equation*}
The function $R$ is continuous and strictly positive on $(0,\infty)$, with $R(0+)=1>0$ and $R(\infty-)=1/2>0$. So, $R(u)\ge\ell$ for all real $u\ge0$, where $\ell\in(0,\infty)$ depends only on $p$ and $K$, and hence only on $p$ (but not on $u$).
Taking now any real $C\ge1$ such that $C^p\ell\ge1$, from \eqref{6} we get $f(Cg(u))\ge u=f(f^{-1}(u))$, which implies $Cg(u)\ge f^{-1}(u)$.

Thus, in view of \eqref{5}, $   g(u)\le f^{-1}(u)\le Cg(u)$. So, \eqref{1} is proved.

Comment: I have another question, for the function $f(x,t):=t^{p(x)}\ln(e+t)$, where $p(\cdot):\Omega\to(1,\infty)$ (this is an example appearing in papers about differential equations), then can I use similar ways to compute its $f^{-1}(x,t):=\inf\{u\geq0:f(x,u)\geq t\}, \forall x\in\Omega, t\geq0$ in the sense of $\approx$?(For two functions $\varphi,\psi:\Omega\times[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$, $\varphi\approx\psi$ means that there exist constants $c_1,c_2>0$, such that $\forall t\geq0$, $\forall x\in\Omega$, $$c_1\varphi(x,t)\leq\psi(x,t)\leq c_2\varphi(x,t).$$  
) how to solve it?

Comment: Thank you very much, I hope you can help me look at the above problem if you are available.

Comment: @user803591 : It is unclear what your $p(x)$ is. If it is bounded, then the extended result will essentially follow from my answer. Anyhow, any additional questions should be asked in separate posts. It appears to me that your posted question has been fully answered. Are you satisfied with it?

Comment: Ok,if $p(x)$ satisfying $\inf_{x\in\Omega} p(x)>1$
 is bounded, then what is the answer of $f^{-1}(x,t)$, can you give me some hint? I want to check it.

Comment: @user803591 : Then the answer should be the same, only with $p$ replaced by $p(x)$. However, that is a separate question, which should be posted and considered separately.

Comment: but if so, then the constants $K$ and $C$ in the previous proof will depend on $x$, how to overcome it? That is to say, how to find constants $K$ and  $C $ that do not depend on $x$?

Comment: @user803591 : The constant $C=C_p$ in the last inequality in the answer will then get replaced by $C_{p(x)}$. I think $C_p$ depends on $p$ continuously or, at least, $C_p$ is bounded if $p$ is bounded. So, if $p(x)$ takes values in a bounded interval $[1,M]$, then you can replace $C=C_p$ by $\tilde C:=\sup\{C_p\colon 1\le p\le M\}<\infty$. However, once again, your posted question has been fully answered, and let us have a closure here, to keep the things in good order. If you need further details or have any other additional questions, please ask them in separate posts.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement and extension of Iosif's answer, let me mention that, more generally, if $$f(t) \sim t^{pq} (\ell(t^q))^p \qquad \text{as } t \to \infty$$ for a *slowly varying function* $\ell$, then $$f^{-1}(s) \sim s^{1/(pq)} (\ell^\#(s^{1/p}))^{1/q} \qquad \text{as } s \to \infty,$$ where $\ell^\#$ is another slowly varying function: the *de Bruijn conjugate* of $\ell$. See Proposition 1.5.15 in *Regular Variation* by Bingham, Goldie and Teugels. If $\ell(t) = \log t$, then $\ell^\#(s) \sim 1 / \log t$, and so we recover an asymptotic variant of the desired result (with $q = 1$).

A variant with asymptotic equality ($\sim$) replaced by comparability ($\approx$) is essentially given as Problem 1.11.19.

Comment: If $p$ replaced by $p(\cdot)$ above, can the detailed proof be found in the reference which you mentioned？

Comment: I do not think I have anything to add to what Iosif wrote in response to your comments under his answer.