# How to compute the left-inverse of $f$ in the sense of $\approx$?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-equations, harmonic-analysis

For two functions $\varphi,\psi:\Omega\times[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$, $\varphi\approx\psi$ means that there exist constants $c_1,c_2>0$, such that $\forall t\geq0$, $\forall x\in\Omega$, $$c_1\varphi(x,t)\leq\psi(x,t)\leq c_2\varphi(x,t).$$

for the function $f(x,t):=t^{p(x)}\ln(e+t)$, where $p(\cdot):\Omega\to(1,\infty)$ is a bounded function (this is an example appearing in papers about differential equations), then how to compute its $f^{-1}(x,t):=\inf\{u\geq0:f(x,u)\geq t\}$, $\forall x\in\Omega$, $t\geq0$ in the sense of $\approx$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Given a specific function $f$, how to compute the left-inverse of $f$ in the sense of $\approx$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409186/given-a-specific-function-f-how-to-compute-the-left-inverse-of-f-in-the-sen)

Comment: @username : The previous question was for $p$ not depending on $x$. Of course, the OP should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 3):

The solution here mainly follows the lines of the [previous answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/409213/36721). For brevity, write $p$ for $p(x)$. The condition that $p$ is bounded from above will not be used. We will only use the condition $p\ge1$.

If $f(t):=t^p\ln(e+t)$ for $p=p(x)\ge1$ and all real $t\ge0$, then
\begin{equation*}
    f^{-1}(u)\approx g(u):=\frac{u^{1/p}}{\ln^{1/p}(e+u^{1/p})} \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
for real $u\ge0$, where the symbol $\approx$ is used in the sense defined in your post.

Indeed, the function $f\colon[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ is continuous and strictly increasing, from $f(0)=0$ to $f(\infty-):=\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)=\infty$. So, $f^{-1}$ is the true inverse of $f$. That is, for all nonnegative real $t$ and $u$ we have
\begin{equation*}
    f(t)=u\iff f^{-1}(u)=t. \tag{2}
\end{equation*}

Next, for real $u\ge0$, let
\begin{equation*}
h(u):=u^{1/p}\,1(u\le e^2)+u^{1/(2p)}\,1(u>e^2) \tag{3}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
    r(u):=\frac{g(u)}{h(u)}.\tag{4} 
\end{equation*}
If $u\le e^2$, then
\begin{equation*}
    r(u)=\frac1{\ln^{1/p}(e+u^{1/p})}\ge\frac1{\ln^{1/p}(e+e^{2/p})}\ge\frac1{\ln(e+e^2)}>4/10, \tag{5} 
\end{equation*}
since $p\ge1$.

Consider now the case $u>e^2$. Let $d(u):=\ln(e+u^{1/p})-\sqrt{u}$. Then $d'(u)2p u (e+u^{1/p})=-e p \sqrt{u}+(2-p\sqrt{u})u^{1/p}\le-0+(2-\sqrt{e^2})u^{1/p}\le0$. So, $d$ is  decreasing on $[e^2,\infty)$ and $d(e^2):=\ln(e+e^{2/p})-e\le\ln(e+e^2)-e<0$. So, $d<0$ on $[e^2,\infty)$ and hence for $u>e^2$ we have $u^{1/(2p)}\ge\ln^{1/p}(e+u^{1/p})$ and hence
\begin{equation*}
    r(u)=\frac{u^{1/(2p)}}{\ln^{1/p}(e+u^{1/p})}\ge1. 
\end{equation*}

Thus, for all real $u\ge0$,
\begin{equation*}
    r(u)\ge K:=4/10. 
\end{equation*}
Therefore and by (1), for all real $u\ge0$,
\begin{equation*}
    Kh(u)\le g(u)\le u^{1/p}. \tag{6}
\end{equation*}
By the second inequality in (6),
\begin{equation*}
f(g(u))=u\,\frac{\ln(e+g(u))}{\ln(e+u^{1/p})}\le u=f(f^{-1}(u)). 
\end{equation*}
Therefore and because $f$ is strictly increasing, we have
\begin{equation*}
g(u)\le f^{-1}(u).\label{5} \tag{7}
\end{equation*}

On the other hand, by the first inequality in (6), for real $C\ge1$
\begin{equation*}
    f(Cg(u))=C^pu\,\frac{\ln(e+Cg(u))}{\ln(e+u^{1/p})} 
    \ge Cu R(u), \tag{8}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
R(u):=\frac{\ln(e+Kh(u))}{\ln(e+u^{1/p})}=\frac{\ln(e+K\tilde h(v))}{\ln(e+v^2)}, \tag{9}
\end{equation*}
where $v:=u^{1/(2p)}$ and $\tilde h(v):=h(v^{2p})\ge\min(v^2,v)$.
So, for all real $u\ge0$,
\begin{equation*}
R(u)\ge\rho(v):=\frac{\ln(e+K\min(v^2,v))}{\ln(e+v^2)}.
\end{equation*}
Note that $\rho$ is continuous and strictly positive on $[0,\infty)$, $\rho(0)=1>0$, and $\rho(v)\to1/2>0$ as $v\to\infty$. So, $\rho(v)\ge c$ for some real $c>0$ and all real $v\ge0$. So, $R(u)\ge c$ for all real $u\ge0$.

Taking now any real $C\ge1$ such that $Cc\ge1$, from (8) we get $f(Cg(u))\ge u=f(f^{-1}(u))$ for all real $u\ge0$, which implies $Cg(u)\ge f^{-1}(u)$.

Thus, in view of (7), $g(u)\le f^{-1}(u)\le Cg(u)$, for some universal real constant $C\ge1$. So, (1) is proved.

Comment: @user803591 : The definition $:=$ in $\tilde h(v):=h(v^{2p})\ge\min(v^2,v)$ is just that, a definition. The inequality here holds just because the only possible values of $h(v^{2p})$ are $v^2$ and $v$. So, $h(v^{2p})$ cannot take a value less than $\min(v^2,v)$.

Comment: I see, It is due to the definition.

Comment: Does $f^{-1}$ satisfy  $f^{-1}(x,t)\approx\min\left\{t^{1/p(x)},\left[\frac{t}{\ln(e+t)}\right]^{1/p(x)}\right\}$? if so, how to prove it?

Comment: This is an extra question. Your posted questions, in this post and the preceding one, have been fully answered, have they not? So, to keep the things in good order, please mark the answers accordingly, and then post separately any additional questions you may have.

Comment: Ok，I have posted it separately.

Comment: @Lele : As I previously wrote, I will consider additional questions from you only after you mark my previous answers accordingly.

Comment: Anyhow, thanks for your detailed explanation.